# A issue about the order of explicit instantiation and explicit specialization

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
void func(T){}

template void func<int>(int);

template<>
void func<int>(int){

}
int main(){

}
```

Consider the above code, `Clang` and `GCC` both complain such code is [ill-formed](https://godbolt.org/z/h9b3Ec), as the below outcome noted.

```
explicit specialization of 'func<int>' after instantiation
```

However, I only find the similar rule :
[temp.expl.spec#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.expl.spec#6)

> If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an **implicit instantiation** to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required. If the program does not provide a definition for an explicit specialization and either the specialization is used in a way that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place or the member is a virtual member function, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. An implicit instantiation is never generated for an explicit specialization that is declared but not defined.

I think such code does not violate the above rule, Note the emphasized part, it says `implicit instantiation`, In my example, such declaration `template void func<int>(int);` is a explicit instantiation definition rather than the specialization that would case an **implicit instantiation**, So why the above code is ill-formed? what's the rule in the standard does the above code violate? Please point the rule out. Thanks.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I have modified my question.

Comment: You might want to change the explicit instantiation `template void func<int>(int);` into a specialization forward declaration `template<> void func<int>(int);` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit fragmented, but the relevant rule here is [[temp.spec]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#5)

> For a given template and a given set of template-arguments, [...]
>
> - both an explicit instantiation and a declaration of an explicit specialization shall not appear in a program unless the explicit instantiation follows a declaration of the explicit specialization. [...]

Comment: Thanks.  very nice!